# Wordpress and Internal Page Links

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, html

I'm trying to construct a Table of Content on a custom template in Wordpress. Because I already know beforehand the headings of the internal sections I want to link to I hardcoded that into the template.

My problem is that in Wordpress it doesn't scroll to that section at all? Here's [the link to a page](http://goodfruitguide.co.uk/fruits/apples#poll_section) with an existing TOC section that's not working.

In terms of code, this is an illustration of what I got:

```
<div class="table_content">
        <h4>Table of Contents</h4>
        <ol>
            <li><a href="#test_link">Overview</a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
```

Which should link to an internal section with the code:

```
<h2><a id="#test_link" class="internal"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

**Note:** I'm using "ID" instead of "name" because it's deprecated in HTML5, which is the doctype I'm using.

I'm also wondering is there an easier way of doing this with jQuery?

Any help in saving my hairline would be GREATLY appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I'm a muppet.

It's got nothing to do with doctypes or Wordpress issues. Just my incorrect, sleep-deprived implementation of HTML.

This

```
<h2><a id="#test_link" class="internal"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

should be

```
<h2><a id="test_link" class="internal"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

Notice the missing "#" in the "ID" attribute, removing that makes everything work nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the separate a element...
http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/text/internallinks.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.